# (Blazor) Select value not updating

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a `<select>` element in my page, of which I want to get the value. To do that, I've added the `@bind=` property. Here's the code:

```html
<form target="#">
    <label for="subject">Vak</label>
    <select @bind="@selectedSubject" id="subject">
        @foreach (Subject subject in Auth.User.Subjects)
        {
            <option value="@subject.Uuid">@subject.Name</option>
        }
    </select><br />
    <!-- (more input fields) -->
<button class="button btn-primary mt-3" @onclick="addNote">Toevoegen</button>
</form>
```

```cs
@code {
    private String selectedSubject { get; set; }
    private String inputTitle { get; set; }
    private String inputContent { get; set; }

    private void addNote()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(selectedSubject);
    }
}
```

This doesn't output anything, and trying to use `selectedSubject` results in a NullReferenceError.
The other values (`inputTitle`, `inputContent`) work as expected.

**Yes**, the `<select>` is properly being filled with `<option>`s.

I've tried switching to whatever `<EditForm>` is, but it kept giving me warnings and failed to build.

Comment: is subject.Uuid a Guid?

Comment: @BrianParker Yes, it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve your issue with things not changing, there are two ways you can do it:

1. Start with a null object for your `SelectedSubject`, do a null check in your click, and have a dummy `select` option that forces you to select an item:

.

```
 <select @onchange=ProcessChange>
    <option selected disabled>Pick a subject. . . </option>
    @foreach (var subject in Auth.User.Subjects) { 
        <option>. . . </option>
    }
</select>
<button @onclick=AddSubject />
    
@code {
    List<Subject> SelectedSubjects = new();
    Subject SelectedSubject {get; set; } = null;
    async Task ProcessChange (ChangeEventArgs args){. . . }
    async Task AddSubject{
       if (Subject is not null) SelectedSubjects.Add (SelectedSubject);
    }
}
```

2. Preselect your first option in your data initialization, and then you don't NEED the dummy `<option>` or the null check.

.

```
@code{
    async Task OnInitializedAsync (bool IsFirstRender){
        Auth.User.Subjects = await LoadSubjectsForUser (Auth.User);
        SelectedSubject = Auth.User.Subjects.First();
    }
}
```

In your use case, I think #1 is probably better.

Comment: Didn't even think of that. Yeah, let's go with #1.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need a form at all.  The main purpose of EditForm is to validate inputs-- like, making sure a password is the correct format.

Also, unless you want to programmatically SET the value of the dropdown, you don't need to bind to it-- instead, use `@onchange`:

```
<select @onchange=ProcessSelection>

. . . 

@code {
    Subject SelectedSubject {get; set;}
    async Task ProcessSelection (ChangeEventArgs args){
        SelectedSubject = Auth.User.Subjects.Single(s=>s.uuid = args.Value.ToString();
        // Process the selection.
    }
}
```

This will (1) give you a place to breakpoint for debugging. (2) Let you do useful things with the `SelectedSubject` object more easily (like add / remove it from a list, pass it as a parameter to a display component, etc.).

Comment: This works, however when there's only one option, it remains null. After all, it never _changes_.

Comment: There are two options to deal with that.  Let me make a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that source code is an instruction of rendering intent so it isn't always clear how your code will react in all cases of operation.

You have to decide whether there will be a selection at all times, or whether no material selection is also valid. For example, if you want an option of "Select a Subject" at the top of the list which is the default, so set am option with that text an a value of Guid.Empty (all zeros). When processing values - just check that the selected Guid is not equal to Guid.Empty if you want to know if a "real" subject option is selected

I use the following two approaches with InputSelect. Note that the Microsoft renderer may set the text of the select to your bound option but may not set that option to "selected"

```
    <InputSelect @bind-Value=MyData>
        <option selected value="@Guid.Empty">Select a Subject</option>
        @foreach (var i in Subjects)
        {
            <option value=@i.Id>@i.SubjectName</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>
```

If you want finer grained control over the select, there is this binding option. As well as a value to which you bind, you also need a function which is called on change - SelectChanged - where you can run other code. you should set the bound value within this method. If the InputSelect is inside a component, the bound value should also have an EventHandler of the same name with the "Changed" text appended - you should Invoke this in your SelectChanged function. Any parent control binding to the child will have its data automatically updated and the SetStateChanged is called for you

```
    <InputSelect Value="@MyValue" ValueChanged="@((Guid value) => SelectChanged(value))" ValueExpression="@(() => MyValue)" >
        @foreach (var i in MyValues)
        {
            if (TheSelectedValue == i.TheValue)
            {
                <option selected value=@i.TheValue>@i.ValueDisplay</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value=@i.TheValue>@i.ValueDisplay</option>
            }
        }
    </InputSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to the problem is different from the other answer.

Here's everything in one Razor component.

1. Separate your data out into a class.  Note that the fields can be null (you may not want them to be).
2. Use `EditForm` with normal binding.  You can then do validation.
3. Logic in select list to determine if no value is selected and display a select message.
4. Separate out the Select code into a separate RenderFragment block to keep the code cleaner.  Not necessary if you like all your markup in one place.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<EditForm EditContext="editContext">

    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <label class="form-label small muted">Subject</label>
        <select class="form-select" @bind="model.Subject">
            @this.SubjectList
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <label class="form-label small muted">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" @bind="model.Title">
    </div>

</EditForm>

<div class="alert alert-info m-3">
    <div class="m-2">
        Subject : @model.Subject
    </div>
    <div class="m-2">
        Title : @model.Title
    </div>
    <div class="m-2">
        Content : @model.Content
    </div>
</div>
@code {

    //private Note model = new() { Subject="Portugal"};
    private Note model = new();

    private EditContext? editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        =>  this.editContext = new EditContext(model);

    private IEnumerable<string> Subjects = new List<string> { "France", "Portugal", "Spain" };

    private bool noSubjectSelected => !Subjects.Any(item => item == model.Subject);

    // Separates out the code into a separate render block
    private RenderFragment SubjectList => (__builder) =>
    {
        if (noSubjectSelected)
        {
            <option disabled selected value="">-- Select a Subject --</option>
        }

        foreach (var subject in Subjects)
        {
            <option value="@subject">@subject</option>
        }
    };

    // Normally separate out into own class file
    public class Note
    {
        public string? Subject { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? Content { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I've left the subject as a string as that's what you have it as.  If it's a guid you will need to adjust the Select Code to handle a Guid/String pair.